# Change Keyboard suggestions? Possible to use reflection if not accessible?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am trying to change the suggestions that occur on top of the keyboard in Android.

Is it possible to use a `ClassLoader` to instantiate an object from the package `com.android.inputmethod.latin` to adjust the suggestions above the keyboard?

Comment: Are you implementing the keyboard? If not, AFAIK the keyboard's views are not in your process and cannot be modified.

Comment: I'm not implementing my own keyboard, I just need to display a suggested list of words above the keyboard that the user should pick

Comment: I'm guessing the other option is to use a `PopupWindow` hide suggestions and show that above the keyboard

Comment: There is no requirement for the suggestions to be at a particular position or size, particularly for different screen sizes. There is no requirement for an input method editor to offer suggestions at all. Then there's the landscape full-screen editor to consider. In short I will be surprised -- and, to be blunt, dismayed -- if what you want is practical.